# C socket programming errors

Tags: c, linux, sockets

It's been an hour since I started looking for THE error. I just started C sockets. The program exits with code `-1` after printing "Error 1 connection error". The server in online, it's a netcat server. Where did I messed up ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HOST "127.0.0.1"
#define PORT 4444

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int sock = 0;
    int ret;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    char *msg = "Hello world !\n";
    char inBuffer[1024] = { 0 };
    if (sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error %d socket creating.\n", sock);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        memset(&server_addr, '0', sizeof(server_addr));

        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
        if (ret = inet_pton(AF_INET, HOST, &server_addr.sin_addr) <= 0)
        {
            printf("Error %d unsuported address: %d\n", ret);
            exit(-2);
        }
        else
        {
            if (ret = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
            {
                printf("Error %d connection error\n", ret);
                exit(-3);
            }
            else
            {
                send(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
                read(sock, inBuffer, 1024);
                printf("%s\n", inBuffer);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: And this is why `if (sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) < 0)` is much better as `int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); if ( sock < 0) ...`  Cramming the assignment into the if-statement is a bad idea.  It gains you nothing, and you just learned just one thing it costs.  There are other things it costs you:  you can't really do anything but simplistic error processing.  Not also  that your `else` is superfluous since you call `exit()` right above it.

Comment: Also, you should also check for errors from the `write` (or `send` as you use for some reason) and `read` calls. Especially, if the other side closes the connection then `read` will return `0` which you need to check for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the expression

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) < 0
```

is actually equal to

```
sock = (socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) < 0)
```

That is, you assign the result of the comparison `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) < 0` to the variable `sock`. The result of that comparison will always be either `0` (for false) or `1` (for true). Neither `0` nor `1` should be a valid socket.

You need to explicitly add parentheses for the assignment:

```
(sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0
```

The same needs to be done for the `connect` call and the comparison there.

Comment: Even better - split the assignment from the error check.  There's no good reason to stuff all that into one line, and there are many reasons to split the assignment from the error checking. Just one: putting the assignment into the error-checking if-statement precludes all but the most simplistic error processing.